# Misplaced Music in Browser

Tags: html, audio

[My local newspaper](http://www.startribune.com/) publishes ads on their website. Sometimes an ad plays obscene music. When I try to complain to the newspaper, they want me to track down the ad with obscene music. Is there a way I can use <kbd>F12</kbd> developer tools to track down the ad with obscene music?

I can try IE, Edge or Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all websites with ads use a service like Google Ads (and the site you're talking about, StarTribune, uses Google Ads as well). These ads are not chosen specifically by the website themselves, so you can not get one specific ad. The site itself **does not host the ads, Google does.** However, you can report the ads *to Google*, since they host the ads. You can report them here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/176378?hl=en